# Coldfusion exception not caught by containing try/catch

Tags: coldfusion

You can run [this cftry gist](https://trycf.com/gist/cb02e1e329d5c0a85e78b87e53fd6741/acf2016?theme=monokai) with either the first or second indicated block of code uncommented to see the problem.

```
<cffunction name="alpha" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="boo" type="boolean" />
    <cfreturn arguments.boo />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="beta">
    <cfset var temp = {} />
    <cftry>
        <cfset temp.userID = 1 />

        <!--- This way throws an *unhandled* exception --->
        <!--- --->
        <cfif alpha(structAppend({userID = temp.userID}, foo))>
            <cfdump var="It worked" />
        </cfif>


        <!--- This way works as expected --->
        <!--- 
        <cfset temp.args = {userID = temp.userID} />
        <cfif alpha(structAppend(temp.args, foo))>
            <cfdump var="It worked" />
        </cfif>
        --->

        <cfcatch>
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch.message#" />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

I know the struct literal notation `{}` will sometimes show generically named structs in my debugger, but why should assigning what's created by such syntax make the struct creation happen at a different time than if it's not assigned?

If I debug, I can set a breakpoint on the line where I set `temp.userID = 1` and it skips right over it.  Moreover, the exception is being thrown on a line contained in a try/catch, but it's failing to catch it.

I know in JavaScript there's the notion of 'hoisting'.  I can only assume in some (but not all!) cases CF is doing something similar to struct literals.

Is this a bug, or a known behavior of CF?

Comment: Seems more like a bug with the *context* used to evaluate the variables, rather than timing. Though agreed the structAppend call should work (and actually does in Lucee). Having said that, what is the use case? Seems like you would *want* to assign the structure to a separate variable in most cases. Otherwise, it cannot be accessed after the call to structAppend ends.

Comment: It seems to work using script syntax - https://trycf.com/gist/ba9f21d27fa6304ecacab255c095e82d/acf2016?theme=monokai (if my conversion is correct) Which leads me to believe it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Agreed. @jinglesthula - FWIW, cftry does not catch all errors. All depends on the type (java.lang.exception versus java.lang.error) and whether it is recoverable. Generally, unrecoverable issues can only be caught in OnError, ecetera.

Comment: @Leigh It's a bit of a contrived example to demonstrate the behavior.  I'm not sure I've ever used the return value of `structAppend` in real life.  Mostly I'm after why it happens so I can avoid the general case.

Comment: @jinglesthula - Basically it sounds like a bug. Seems to work just fine if you do not try to capture the return value (the cftry works as well). IIRC, it is one of those pointless return values that is always `true`. So not being able to use that particular expression probably is not a big issue. Though, agreed it *should* work as written.